# SQL code not working, unknown error

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

I have written a piece of code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test()
BEGIN
  DECLARE 
    ok INT default FALSE;
    curs_r1 CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM t WHERE (b > 1 and b < 3) and (c < 2);
    curs_r2 CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM t WHERE (a = 1) and (b > 2);
    CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET ok = TRUE;


  SET ok = False; 
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t;
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t  (
    id int,
    a int,
    b int,
    c int
  );
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS res;
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS res  (
    id int not null unique,
    score float
  );

  insert into t values (0,1,2,3), (1,1,3,2), (2,3,2,1);

  --------------------------------------------
  OPEN curs_r1;
  SET score_r1 = 0.5;
  REPEAT
    FETCH curs_r1 INTO 
    id, a, b, c;
    INSERT IGNORE INTO res VALUES (id, score_r1);
  UNTIL ok END REPEAT;
  CLOSE curs_r1;

  --------------------------------------------
  SET ok = FALSE;

  OPEN curs_r2;
  SET score_r2 = 0.25;
  REPEAT
    FETCH curs_r2 INTO 
    id, a, b, c;
    INSERT IGNORE INTO res VALUES (id, score_r2);
  UNTIL ok END REPEAT;
  CLOSE curs_r2;

  

  SELECT * FROM res;
END
```

but this is generating too many errors like:

> Error: near line 1: near "PROCEDURE": syntax  Error
>
> Error: near line 5: near "curs_r1": syntax  Error
>
> Error: near line 6: near "curs_r2": syntax  Error
>
> Error: near line 7: near "CONTINUE": syntax  Error
>
> Error: near line 10: near "SET": syntax  Error
>
> Error: near line 27: near "OPEN": syntax  Error
>
> Error: near line 28: near "SET": syntax  Error
>
> Error: near line 29: near "REPEAT": syntax  Error
>
> Error: near line 32: near "IGNORE": syntax  Error
>
> Error: near line 33: near "UNTIL": syntax  Error
>
> Error: near line 34: near "CLOSE": syntax  Error
>
> Error: near line 37: near "SET": syntax  Error
>
> Error: near line 39: near "OPEN": syntax  Error
>
> Error: near line 40: near "SET": syntax  Error
>
> Error: near line 41: near "REPEAT": syntax  Error
>
> Error: near line 44: near "IGNORE": syntax  Error
>
> Error: near line 45: near "UNTIL": syntax  Error
>
> Error: near line 46: near "CLOSE": syntax  Error
>
> Error: incomplete SQL: END

does anyone have an idea about the root cause please?

thank you very much in advance.

---

The errors above where fixed (thank you Darwin for the first clue) and here is the new piece of code:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test;
CREATE PROCEDURE test()
BEGIN
  DECLARE ok INT default FALSE;
  DECLARE score_r1 FLOAT default 0.5;
  DECLARE score_r2 FLOAT default 0.25;
  DECLARE id, a, b, c INT;
  DECLARE curs_r1 CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM t WHERE (b > 1 and b < 3) and (c < 2);
  DECLARE curs_r2 CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM t WHERE (a = 1) and (b > 2);
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET ok = TRUE;

  SET ok = False; 
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t;
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t  (
    id int,
    a int,
    b int,
    c int
  );
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS res;
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS res  (
    id int not null unique,
    score float
  );

  insert into t values (0,1,2,3), (1,1,3,2), (2,3,2,1);

  OPEN curs_r1;
  OPEN curs_r2;
  
  REPEAT
    FETCH curs_r1 INTO id, a, b, c;
    INSERT IGNORE INTO res VALUES (id, score_r1);
  UNTIL ok END REPEAT;
  CLOSE curs_r1;

  SET ok = FALSE;

  
  REPEAT
    FETCH curs_r2 INTO id, a, b, c;
    INSERT IGNORE INTO res VALUES (id, score_r2);
  UNTIL ok END REPEAT;
  CLOSE curs_r2;

  SELECT * FROM res;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

in the output, I am expecting to see two lines with id = 2 and id = 1
but I am having only one line with id=0 and score=0.5

what am I missing here?
thank you very much

Comment: By cutting off your error message where you did, you've eliminated the most informative part of it.

Comment: near what  ?.. show the rest of message .. is the best part

Comment: First thing I notice is only the first variable has the required `DECLARE`. _Also, generally bad form to use `SELECT *` in a cursor, but since you've got the table creations in the proc, it's not entirely horrible._

Comment: You cut the error message exactly where it tells you where the error is.

Comment: What are you using to write and/or execute this? MySQL Workbench should give you at least a basic framework to start with so you don't error on line 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So essentially you're getting an error message on every statement. In order to create a procedure from the `mysql` client you must enclose the entire `CREATE` statement within `DELIMITER` directives, like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE test()
  BEGIN
  ... --code body goes here
  END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

You do have many other errors in your code, but that will solve the first one.

For more information on `DELIMITER`, search the Stack Overflow archives.

Comment: thanks for the first tip, unblocking me there helped me debug the rest. could you please have an additional look at my edit? thanks a lot

Comment: it is ok now, changing the variable names fixed it. thank you

Comment: Looks okay for the most part, although I notice you aren't doing anything with the data you `FETCH` from your cursor.